# Return adjacent duplicates in Erlang

Tags: recursion, erlang

I'm trying to learn recursion in Erlang and I am working through a book.
But I'm hitting a wall when faced with the problem of taking a list and returning only the duplicate elements.
I tried writing a function which returns only the unique elements and then removing them from the original list.

```
adjacent_dups(L) -> L -- uniques(L).

uniques([])    -> [];
uniques([H|T]) -> [H | [X || X <- uniques(T), X /= H]].
```

This will however not give the correct result when the list is not well structured.

```
L = [7,3,4,3]
```

My code will return

```
adjacent_dups([7,3,4,3]) -> 3
```

How can I get

```
adjacent_dups([7,3,4,3]) -> []
```

Comment: This is underspecified: what output do you expect for e.g. [2,3,3,4,1,1] how is the result to be ordered or not.  What should happen with [6,4,4,4,3,1,1,1,1] ?  And what about [1,2,3,3,4,3,3] ?

Comment: This is actually a very similar problem to the one Dave Thomas mentioned in his talk last year at ElixirConf. Here is a link to the relevant portion of the talk: https://youtu.be/5hDVftaPQwY?t=12m18s

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only want adjacent duplicates you can try pattern matching them out pairwise from your list. Here is a naive solution to get you started. It assumes that duplicates are only found in pairs (never three in a row, for example):

```
adjacent_dups([]) -> [];
adjacent_dups([A,A|Tail]) -> [A|adjacent_dups(Tail)];
adjacent_dups([_Head|Tail]) -> adjacent_dups(Tail).
```

If we think a little bit more about it we might realize that we can handle triplets in the same way. And by making that case only consume the first value and put the other two back we can actually make it generic enough to work even if there are more than two in a row. Watch the magic:

```
adjacent_dups([]) -> [];
adjacent_dups([A,A,A|Tail]) -> adjacent_dups([A,A|Tail]);
adjacent_dups([A,A|Tail]) -> [A|adjacent_dups(Tail)];
adjacent_dups([_Head|Tail]) -> adjacent_dups(Tail).
```

Here is the output:

```
adjacent_dups([1,1,1,1,2,3,4,55,55,6,7,8,8,8,1]).
[1,55,8]
```

Answer (score 5):

Use pattern matching in the function head to find adjacent identical values:

```
adjacent_dups(L) ->
    adjacent_dups(L, #{}).
adjacent_dups([], Acc) ->
    maps:keys(Acc);
adjacent_dups([H,H|T], Acc) ->
    adjacent_dups(T,maps:put(H,H,Acc));
adjacent_dups([_|T], Acc) ->
    adjacent_dups(T, Acc).
```

The first function `adjacent_dups/1` is meant to be exported. The rest, `adjacent_dups/2`, are helper functions.

The `adjacent_dups/1` function creates an empty map to pass to `adjacent_dups/2` as the initial value of an accumulator. Recursive functions often use accumulators.

The first clause of `adjacent_dups/2` handles the case where the incoming list has been exhausted or was empty to start with. In that case, we retrieve the keys of the accumulator map; these are our adjacent values.

The second clause of `adjacent_dups/2` handles the case of adjacent values using pattern matching. In this case, we add the value as a key and value to the accumulator map, and call ourselves recursively with the tail of the list. Using a map eliminates duplicates from the final result.

The final clause of `adjacent_dups/2` handles the case where a value does not have an adjacent value; it simply makes a recursive call with the tail of the list and an unmodified accumulator.

Comment: The answer already explains that maps allow us to eliminate duplicates from the result. Using them means there's no need to check if the value has already been seen; instead, just add it to the map. If we used a list instead, we'd have to walk the list for each accumulator insertion to see if it's already there, and not add it if already present.

Comment: Depends ob what the spec would be, the problem is underspecified in the question.  This solution outputs each duplicated value only once and in arbitrary order

Comment: The title asks for one thing, and the question asks for another.

Comment: The problem is that maps are has `O(log(N))` access time. It's not better than `lists:usort` the result, but more complex